# How to create array of object from tow arrays with extra properties?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, object

I need help to create an array of objects from two exiting array

```
["A","B","C"]
[1,2,3]
```

What I want is something like the below:

```
[{name: "A", id: 1, trash: false},{name: "B", id: 2, trash: false},{name: "C", id: 3, trash: false}]
```

properties should be defined as I want it like ***name*** and ***id*** and the value of them should come from existing arrays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using [`Array.prototype.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Map) that ***creates a new array populated with the results of calling a provided function on every element in the calling array***.

```js
var arr1 = ["A","B","C"]
var arr2 = [1,2,3] 
var resArr = arr1.map((i,idx) => ({name: i, id: arr2[idx], trash: false}));
console.log(resArr);
```

Comment: it is a very nice solution thank you very much but I forgot to mention in arr2 numbers are saved as string so is there any quick way to convert them to the intiger in the map() method?

Comment: @MohammadKhavari, simply prefix the arr2 value with `+`....like `id: +arr2[idx]`:)

Answer (score 2):

Hope this code helping you

```
const array = ["A","B","C"]
const num = [1,2,3] 
array.map((o,index)=>({name: o,id:num[index],trash:false}))
```